# Can I use the same CA signed certificate that was used in the old org

Tags: apex, certificates

If I create a new Salesforce org,

Can I use the same CA signed certificate that was used in the old org to do domain masking in the new Salesforce org.

Assuming I no longer use the CA Signed certificate in the old org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , if the cn and other properties are same